# d3 js circular bar plot, how to pass a object instead of a .csv file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

How can i alter this code:
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/circular_barplot_basic.html

```
d3.csv("https://raw.gith.....
```

To have it accept my object, from inside my code, instead of the linked csv:
My object:

```
{0: 3
1: 7
2: 9
3: 2
.....
}
```

Also: Do i need to add a "header" with column-names for my object to have it accepted (Switching out Country and Value from the referenced csv file) ?

I have tried to add it as d3.json according to this site:
https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#csv
But it seems that all methods require a path, and my array in the current scope (?), and not a file in a path. (It is called scope, is it not?)

Comment: What are be the domain of your x-axis? In that example, it is `Country`.

Comment: Degrees in intervals of 5. So bar 1 will be the sum of elements in index 0 to 4.

Comment: I see.. Anyways i doubt that is crucial to this question. You may wanna check out my answer. It probably solves your problem of displaying the graph using an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert it from an object, to an array of objects.

Assuming this is the object you are working with:

```
const obj = {
  0: 30,
  1: 200,
  2: 900,
  3: 2000,
}
```

And the keys are similar to the one given on the example, whereby `Country` will be represented by the X scale, and `Value` will be represented by the Y scale.

```js
const obj = {
  0: 30,
  1: 200,
  2: 900,
  3: 2000,
}
const data = Object.entries(obj).map(element => {
  return {
    Country: element[0],
    Value: element[1]
  }
});
console.log(data)
```

This will give you the correct data format that is to be used for the D3.js Circular area plot.

I have reproduced the demo over [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x45zq3ra/). Click 'run', and you might have to scroll down in order to view the graph.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was trying to solve, i will try to implement.

Comment: Worked good. Dont know why, but i was always thinking that i needed to keep the d3.xxx( ...  function.

Comment: @otk Are you referring to `d3.csv()`? You only need that if you are importing a CSV file!